# Open source CMS choice: REST in REST out

Tags: angularjs, rest, content-management-system

**TL;DR**: Can you recommend a REST-oriented, flexible-schema, open source CMS?

My product has two customer facing sides, so I need to build two custom front ends (both REST-powered angular single-page apps).

Publishers will use the first website (ANGULAR1) to authenticate to the CMS and insert their content (via REST).
Subscribers will use the second website (ANGULAR2) to authenticate to the CMS and to READ the content and to subscribe/unsubscribe/rate the published content (via REST).

The domain I have to model in the CMS is not really standard blog-style, but more hierarchical: every publication has curators profile, authors profiles, venues for events..

A CDN is part of the requirement for the multimedia content and attachments.

Here is how this should work in a schetch:

[image: required architecture]

For now, I only saw blog engines, SaaS CMSs or other CMSs that mandate their own GUI for data insert, whereas I really need the REST API to insert content.

Answer (score 0):

I am also investing this question.

Actually I found http://octobercms.com which is a new and interessting CMS and there is a plugin http://octobercms.com/plugin/uxms-restful that let you desgin and manage RESTfull APIs.

There is also http://jarves.io/ but you cannot yet try it out... but it uses angular.js and has a REST api from what they describe.

That is the best solution I could find for now.